# RestKit Nested Mappings Error 0.20.0

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit-0.20

I am trying to use the latest RestKit in one of my iPhone App.

The JSON string that i get is

> {
>       "testdata": 1374226642,
>       "errorCode": null,
>       "errorMessage": null,
>       "mycontent": {
>           "myid": "1",
>           "name": "mrbala",
>           "textmessage": [
>               "text1231",
>               "text1232",
>               "text1234"
>           ],
>           "picturemessage": [
>               "text1231",
>               "text1232",
>               "text1234"
>           ],
>           "mydate": "0",
>           "yourdate": "0"
>       } }

My code is as follows.

```
@interface TextMessage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,strong)NSString *textmessage;

@end
```

PictureMessage

```
@interface PictureMessage : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *picturemessage;

@end
```

My Content

```
@interface MyContent : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *myid;

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *name;

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSArray *textMessage;

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSArray *pictureMessage;

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *mydate;

@property (nonatomic,copy)NSString *yourdate;

@end
```

MainItem

```
@interface WeatherService : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSDate *testData;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *errorCode;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *errorMessage;
@property (nonatomic,strong)MyContent *mycontent;

@end
```

Mappings are as

```
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKNSJSONSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"text/html"];

RKObjectMapping *textmessage = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[TextMessage class]];
[textmessage addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"textmessage"]];

RKObjectMapping *picturemessage = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[PictureMessage class]];
[picturemessage addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMapping attributeMappingFromKeyPath:nil toKeyPath:@"picturemessage"]];

RKObjectMapping *mycontent = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyContent class]];

[mycontent addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"myid": @"myid",
 @"name" : @"name",
 @"mydate":@"mydate",
 @"yourdate":@"yourdate"}];

[mycontent addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"textmessage" toKeyPath:@"textmessage" withMapping:textmessage]];

[mycontent addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"picturemessage" toKeyPath:@"picturemessage" withMapping:picturemessage]];

RKObjectMapping *mainitem = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MainItem class]];

[mainitem addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"testdata" : @"requestDate",
 @"errorCode" : @"errorCode",
 @"errorMessage" : @"errorMessage"}];

[mainitem addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"newsContent" toKeyPath:@"newsContent" withMapping:mycontent]];

NSIndexSet *statusCodes = RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful); // Anything in 2xx

RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mainitem method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:nil keyPath:@"" statusCodes:statusCodes];

NSString *lURL = @"http://xxx.xxx.143.139/test.json";

NSString *lModified  = [[lURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:lModified];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[responseDescriptor]];

[objectRequestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){
    RKLogInfo(@"Load Collection of Articles : %@",mappingResult.array);

    NSMutableArray *lArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:mappingResult.array];
    for (int i=0; i < [mappingResult.array count]; i++) {

        MainItem  *lArticle = [lArray objectAtIndex:i];

        for (int l=0;l < lArticle.newsContent.textmessage.count; l++){
            TextMessage *lMessage = [lArticle.newsContent.textmessage objectAtIndex:l];
            NSLog(@"Message :: %@",[lMessage textmessage]);
        }

        for (int l=0;l < lArticle.newsContent.picturemessage.count; l++){
            PictureMessage *lMessage = [lArticle.newsContent.picturemessage objectAtIndex:l];
            NSLog(@"Picture :: %@",[lMessage picturemessage]);
        }

        NSLog(@"Article :: %@",[lArticle  requestDate]);
    }
}failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    RKLogError(@"Operation Failed :: %@",error);
}];

[objectRequestOperation start];
```

Everything works fine. Only when I try to print the message text, it also prints the complete mapping info. The line  NSLog(@"Message :: %@",[lMessage textmessage]); prints complete mapping info. I cannot simply access textMessage. This is what is output.

```
Message :: text1231 ({
    HTTP =     {
        request =         {
            URL = "http://xxx.xxx-xxx.xx/mycontent/?id=1";
            headers =             {
            };
            method = GET;
        };
        response =         {
            URL = "http://xxx.xxx-xxx.xx/mycontent/?id=1";
            headers =             {
                Connection = "Keep-Alive";
                "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
                Date = "Fri, 19 Jul 2013 11:12:16 GMT";
                Server = "Apache/2.2.22";
                "Set-Cookie" = "fe_typo_user=9862282e43cabf58a4226fe92338877b; path=/";
                "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
                "X-Pad" = "avoid browser bug";
                "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.3.19";
            };
        };
};
mapping =     {
    collectionIndex = 2;
    rootKeyPath = "";
};
```

})

Is there any missing part in this ?

Regards,

Nirav

Comment: Change your log statement to: `NSLog(@"Message (%@) :: %@", NSStringFromClass([[lMessage textmessage] class]), [lMessage textmessage]);

Comment: Thanks Wain. It worked. Is there a straight forward way to get the Message class directly from the response ?

Comment: What kind of class is being returned. Is it some proxy which is giving a custom description?